# Wordpress frontpage not displaying template's content

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this wordpress template created from scratch.
However, the static front page is not pulling the template properly (I have already selected the one I wanted in the Pages Panel).

When I apply the same template to another page, it works fine, but as soon as I make that the new front page, I get nothing again.

I'm not quite sure what is wrong, since the one I have created works fine (when it's not the front page) and when I try to type a text directly into the index.php to test if it's pulling it instead, blank page again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a template named "front-page.php" or "home.php" (with "front-page.php" having the higher priority) inside the theme folder, this template will be used for displaying the page assigned as homepage. So either there is such a template in your folder, or if not, you might try to copy or rename your working template to "front-page.php"

See also https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png

Comment: There was actually a front-page.php in the folder when I imported the folder and I haven't noticed it. Thanks for the help, mate. You saved someone from having a cancer today.